# In a .Net web site, what are my options for sending email alerts when folder contents change?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I don't know much about the .Net environment, so my first idea was to just write a console app that scans the folder for new content, and then emails alerts out.  Then put the .exe as a scheduled task on the server, executing every few minutes.  This seems pretty archaic to me though.  Is there a more elegant way to do this for my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what type of application you choose the way to get notifications about folder changes in .NET is through the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class. A good approach would be to [create a Windows Service](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WindowsService.aspx) which will run in background and listen for notifications.

Comment: Is a windows service my only option?  I was hoping to have something contained completely in the website data and configuration files.

Comment: Of course not, you could always use the `FileSystemWatcher` in your ASP.NET application, no problem here.

Comment: This is what I'm after.  How do I instantiate the FileSystemWatcher on app startup, and have it stay running?

Comment: You instantiate it in the `Application_Start` event in your `global.asax` file. Then you assign the event handlers you are interested in watching for and they will be triggered when those events occur so that you can send your email, that's all.

Comment: That's what I was after.  Thanks!

Comment: Just because I am curious: What if IIS recycles the worker thread and nothing is there to hit the website and spin it up again? I'd just add a console app that 'pings' the website every few minutes just to make sure the w3wp thread is always alive.

Comment: If IIS recycles the worker thread everything ends there. No more notifications. The first user request that comes in will restart the process. That's one of the reasons why you might prefer using a Windows Service - there's nothing that might recycle it.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  This is helpful.  I suppose I wrote my subject line poorly.  What I'm actually after is what's the proper way to execute the code on a timer, or start it up at application startup and keep it running.  Is there something in the global.asax file I can make that will execute something on a timer?  I'd rather not write a console app and have windows scheduled tasks execute it, it seems flaky, also if someone moves the website they have to remember to move the scheduled task as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). Create a Windows Service that constantly runs, and attach an Event to the Watcher to send out emails.

Note that this reports every change, sometimes multiple ones (e.g., moving a file is a delete and create I think), so you may want to limit the number of emails you sent. Experiment a bit before sending hundreds of emails or so - been there, done that :)

Comment: Is a windows service my only option?  I was hoping to have something contained completely in the website data and configuration files.